# How to rerender a4j:outputpanel whic is inside the c:foreach loop

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, richfaces

How to re render the a4j:output panelwhich is inside the c:foreach loop?Because the id of the a4j:outputpanel which is in c:foreach is dynamically generated.If i rerender using the static id its rerender only the first one.How can i achieve this?Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using c:foreach loop does not add the JSF components into the JSF view tree with unique ID's. Therefore you cannot provide IDs of the components to re-render.

If you want to re-render dynamically created a4j:outputPanel components, better way would be by building the a4j:outputPanels through Java code.

You can also try to re-render the outer a4j:outputPanel :

```
<a4j:outputPanel id="outer-wrapper">
     <c:foreach>
         <a4j:outputPanel>

         </a4j:outputPanel>
     </c:foreach>
</a4j:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Hi Ravi,Thx for your reply.If i rerender the outer a4j:outputpanel its rerender all the rich:panel in the loop.But i need to rerender the single one like(second or third etc.).Is there any other way?

Comment: Just through JSF tags, No, I don't think so. 

You would have to create the entire component list in Java, maintain the list of id's assigned to the a4j:outputPanel's and then use those id's in the re-render attribute.

Comment: Hi Ravi,Thx for your reply.I will try to do that.